# UISlider missing track images in iOS 5

Tags: ios, ios5, uislider

I have a UISlider, and I set custom trackImages and thumbImage, using the following code:

```
[progress setMinimumTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"scrubbar-inactive.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[progress setMaximumTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"scrubbar-active.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[progress setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"scrubbar-ball.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[progress setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"scrubbar-ball.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Everything works fine, but in iOS 5 infrequently I get only the thumbImage and no trackImages underneath.

Comment: Where do you create your UISlider? IB or code?

Comment: IB. I'm extending UITableViewCell and that code is in awakeFromNib.

Comment: So can't you just set the trackImages?

Comment: You can set the track images in interface builder l

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you're updating `progress.value` in a timer and not checking for NaN values.
Just add a checking for NaN this way:

```
//a necessary value for a slider
NSTimeInterval sliderPosition = ...;

if (sliderPosition != sliderPosition)
    return;    //NaN detected
else
    [progress setValue:sliderPosition animated:NO];
```

There is also a constant called `NAN`, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Well, I have the similar problem today. The track image wasn't displayed on iOS5 but it was ok on iOS4. So I decided as your topic doesn't have an answer yet it could help you. That's strange but **value** set to **NaN** can dismiss a custom track image. Ignore if it's not your case.

Comment: This worked out and allowed to show the desired image.
Just setting the slider value to 0 fixed the bug, there is no need to use the "resizableImageWithCapInsets"
THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem before where the track images always show up okay in iOS 4 but not in iOS 5. I tried to make the images resizable. And it worked for me. Please try this:

```
UIImage *leftTrackImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"progress_left.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 0)];
UIImage *rightTrackImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"progress_right.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 0)];
```